# makeJar not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I want to make a jar file from my android project in Android Studio
I added this code in my build.gradle :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmjOv.jpg)

And then i dbclick on makeJar in gradle window.
But after BUILD SUCCESSFUL there is not my jar file!

Where is my problem?
Thank you.

Comment: just a suggestion but you can use aar too do you need the res folder to be included ?

Comment: I need to jar file , because i want to call that in unity3d